# Integral of probability function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm reading the book "Mathematics for Machine Learning".

In probability and distributions section I hit this formula:

> if $\mathbf x =[x_1 ,...,x_D ]^ T$ we obtain the marginal  $$p(x_{i})
> = \int p(x_1 ,...,x_D )d\mathbf x _{\setminus i}$$ by repeated application of the sum rule where we integrate/sum out all random
> variables except $x_i$

I can't understand it. Can someone explain it ? Or provide an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you have is a statement of the marginal probability of a random variable $x_i$. This means that it is the probability of $x_i$ occurring alone, not related to any other variables.

To calculate this probability, we start with the joint probability $p(x_1 ,...,x_D )$ which is the probability of all $D$ variables occurring together. To calculate the marginal probability $p(x_{i})$, we need to "integrate/sum out" all other random variables except $x_i$. This means that we need to sum over all possible values of the remaining variables. We can do this by repeatedly applying the sum rule. This can be written as:

$$p(x_{i}) = \int p(x_1 ,...,x_D )d\mathbf x _{\setminus i}$$

where $\mathbf x _{\setminus i}$ are all variables other than $x_i$.

An example of this in action could be if you have three random variables, $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$. The joint probability of these three occurring together would be $p(x_1 , x_2, x_3)$. To calculate the marginal probability of $x_1$ alone, we need to integrate/sum out the other two variables while leaving $x_1$ fixed. This can be written as:

$$p(x_1) = \int p(x_1, x_2, x_3) dx_2 dx_3$$

Therefore, integrating/summing out the other two variables allows us to obtain the marginal probability of $x_1$ occurring alone.

Comment: You said x1 , x2 and x3 are random variables, I think my confusion is here. I thought that they are states that a random variavle X can be. If they are random variables so p(x1) should be a function, not a number . Am I right?

Comment: @MohammadAliZeraatkar It is the notation from your book quotation.  $p(x_1 ,\ldots ,x_D )$ looks like a joint probability density function, i.e. the probability density at the $D$-dimensional point $\mathbf{x} =(x_1 ,\ldots ,x_D )$, while $p(x_i)$ looks like a marginal density function.  Ultimately it is for the book to define what it means by its notation and to try to distinguish between a random variable and the values it takes